# C# Parse a dynamic JSON JToken to a List

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, linq-to-json

Can we parse a dynamic JSON to a List of Object `List<DiffModel>`

```cs
public class DiffModel 
{
  public string Property { get; set; }
  public string OldValue { get; set; }
  public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON is generated  with the help of a [library](https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net)  which helps to compare 2 JSON objects and find out the differences.  The differences are getting stored as a `JToken`

Sample JSON JToken value generated with help of
`JToken patch = jdp.Diff(left, right)` method

```json
{
  "Id": [
    78485,
    0
  ],
  "ContactId": [
    767304,
    0
  ],
  "TextValue": [
    "text value",
    "text14"
  ],
  "PostCode": [
    null
  ]
}
```

From the JSON the value of first item in the object is

```
DiffModel [0] =  Property ="id" OldValue="78485" NewValue="0"
DiffModel [1] =  Property ="contactId" OldValue="767304" NewValue="0"
DiffModel [2] =  Property ="TextValue" OldValue="text value" NewValue="text14"
DiffModel [3] =  Property ="PostCode" OldValue= null NewValue=null
```

Can we navigate between the properties of dynamic JSON and build a similar model

Comment: For your particular case, you could use `patch.AsJEnumerable().OfType<JProperty>().Select(p=>new DiffModel { ... })`. However, the returned `JToken` isn't as simple as your example. You can read the [full specs](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/docs/deltas.md).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a data model like this:

```
struct DiffModel
{
    public string Property { get; init; }
    public object OldModel { get; init; }
    public object NewModel { get; init; }
}
```

I've used `struct` but you can use `class`, `record` whatever you prefer.

Then you can convert the `JToken` to a `Dictionary<string, object[]>`.

- The key will be the property name
- the value will be the property values

```
var rawModel = patch.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object[]>>();
```

Finally, all you need is a mapping between the `DiffModel` and the `KeyValuePair<string, object[]>`:

```
var diffModels = rawModel
    .Select(pair => new DiffModel
    {
        Property = pair.Key,
        OldModel = pair.Value.First(),
        NewModel = pair.Value.Last(),
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 
" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object[]]'. Path ''.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object[]].  This is the error i was getting

Comment: @Sebastion I've used your json as an input for my conversion (`JToken patch = JObject.Parse(json)`). I haven't experienced that problem which has been mentioned by you. But let me double check.

Comment: @Sebastian I could not reproduce your exception. Could you please share in your question your `left` and `right` variables to be able to generate the diff on my local machine as well?

Comment: The value of patch is like below 
{
  "Id": [
    78487,
    0
  ],
  "ContactId": [
    767304,
    0
  ],
  "TextValue": [
    "scs re gregre",
    "asdas"
  ]
}

Comment: @Sebastian I've copy-pasted your above sample json and it works fine. You can check it here as well: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0jt3z

Comment: My bad The initial step of parsing the string to JSON was missing in my code block . Looks like this  is  working in normal use cases. I have to debug further to see how its handling the null values [ either in new or old value section ]